# onHandleIntent sometimes work and sometimes not

Tags: android, intentservice

you got to help me out here. I'm on this for few days now and I have no clue what's the problem and things are already in production.

I have very simple IntentService which runs fine and uploads a very big strings (Images in Base64) to a server

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(NewDiscussionActivity.this, PostNewDiscussionIntentService.class);
        setNewDiscussionIntentExtras(intent, discussionId, postId);
        startService(intent);
```

For some reason the IntentService is sometimes called and sometimes it is not called. The constructor is called

```
public PostNewDiscussionIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}
```

but the `onHandleIntent` is not called and nothing happens.

I suspected that at some point one of the IntentServices is crashed and the following calls to onHandleIntent are not running. I read that there was some kind of problem in api level 9 which was fixed by api level 10. But this is not the case, for me it is inconsistently sometimes works and sometimes it doesn't. 
Can anyone suggest what might caused my problem? My min Sdk is 11 and I run the application on 4.4.2. Thank you very much.

Comment: override onStartCommand and add some Log.d calls and see what happens

Comment: I'll do that and will be back with more info. Thanks.

Comment: I've override onStartCommand and apparently when onHandleIntent is not called then onStartCommand is not called either. So, what might be the reason for an IntentService not to be called?

Comment: So you have cases when you call startService but onStartCommand is not called?

Comment: Yep. That's right. I have no clue where to go from here. I've been on this for few days now. Checked everything, tried everything. Waiting for any idea.

Comment: did you check what startService returns?

Comment: startService returns just fine. A ComponentName holding the name of the IntentService.

Comment: My activity calls the camera for taking picture and then lets the user crop the image using simplecropimage library. Does anyone know this library for cropping images? https://github.com/biokys/cropimage . Can it be related to the problem in any way?

Comment: so the only reason is your extras are too big (a limit is 1MB IIRC) use bound service if its a local service to pass your data directly

Comment: Are you serious??? I think you just saved my day! My extras are way bigger than 1MB I believe. I didn't know about this limitation. I'll get to check it right away. I'll be back with my results. Thanks!

Comment: man, you're the best. I would not find this in a million years. thanks a lot. would you like to answer this? I'll mark it as answer. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness I'm posting @pskink's solution.
I didn't know that EXTRAS HAVE SIZE LIMIT.
I'm not sure what the limit is, I just take it as 1MB. Anything bigger than that I use other ways to pass data between activities.

Here are the words of @psking:

> so the only reason is your extras are too big (a limit is 1MB IIRC)
>   use bound service if its a local service to pass your data directly